# BeagleBone Black cant connect to internet via Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, beagleboneblack

I cant seem to connect to the internet with my beaglebone black (Debian 10 buster) via a ethernet cable which is connected to my laptop.

It was working yesterday but for some reason it decided to just stop working. Here is my putty setup:
 [image]

When i try to ping 8.8.8.8 i receive the following error:

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.193.76 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.193.76 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.193.76 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.193.76 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I tried setting a static ip for the beaglebone black by adding the following to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface eth0 inet static 
        address 192.168.1.102 
        netmask 255.255.255.0 
        gateway 192.168.1.254 
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 
        dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

But still no luck.
Does anybody know how i can fix my network issue? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if the question is still valid --- It is good that you provided network configuration of your BBB. Can you provide routes of your BBB (``route -n``) and ``ifconfig`` output. And do the same with respect to your native machine. And how is your native machine getting internet access ?  And pls explain the environment of your native machine, the OS it is running on like such